# How to restrict joint rotations in CCD

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inverse-kinematics, cyclic-coordinate-descent

I struggle desperately with maths, to try and improve I've been trying to create an IK solution in Unity.

I have made a simple CCD algorithm which behaves as intended: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZvdZGUxbbc

But when I try adding constraints to the joint angles the behaviour is innacurate and distorted: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1YY9KqqaYY

Currently I have a for loop which iterates through all the joints in the chain while target is not reached and current attempts < attemptsthreshold.

Once the corrective rotation for each joint is calculated, I apply it to joint[i].
I then check the rotation at each joint, clamping it within it's min-max range.

Here is the code which applies rotation, then checks the rotation limits:

```cs
Vector3 vectorCurrJointToEndEffector = (joints[joints.Length - 1].transform.position - joints[i].transform.position).normalized; //normalised vector from current joint to end effector position
Vector3 vectorCurrJointToTarget = (target.transform.position - joints[i].transform.position).normalized; //normalised vector from current joint to targetposition

float cosineAngle = Vector3.Dot(vectorCurrJointToEndEffector, vectorCurrJointToTarget); //dot product gives the cosine of the angle for the corrective rotation

//limit possibilities
if (cosineAngle < 1)
{
    Vector3 crossProduct = Vector3.Cross(vectorCurrJointToEndEffector, vectorCurrJointToTarget).normalized; //normalised cross product gives the axis on which to rotate the joint

    float toRotateDegrees = Mathf.Acos(cosineAngle) * Mathf.Rad2Deg; //calculate joint rotation in degrees

    joints[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(toRotateDegrees, crossProduct) * joints[i].transform.rotation; //apply joint rotation

    joints[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(toRotateDegrees, crossProduct) * joints[i].transform.rotation; //apply joint rotation


    //clamp current joint rotation within set limits
    Vector3 currentJointEulerAngles = joints[i].joint.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;

    if (currentJointEulerAngles.x > 180f)
        currentJointEulerAngles.x -= 360f;
    currentJointEulerAngles.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentJointEulerAngles.x, joints[i].XaxisMin, joints[i].XaxisMax);

    if (currentJointEulerAngles.y > 180f)
        currentJointEulerAngles.y -= 360f;
    currentJointEulerAngles.y = Mathf.Clamp(currentJointEulerAngles.y, joints[i].YaxisMin, joints[i].YaxisMax);

    if (currentJointEulerAngles.z > 180f)
        currentJointEulerAngles.z -= 360f;
currentJointEulerAngles.z = Mathf.Clamp(currentJointEulerAngles.z, joints[i].ZaxisMin, joints[i].ZaxisMax);

    joints[i].joint.transform.localEulerAngles = currentJointEulerAngles;
```

As shown in the second video, the result is very poor.

Could anyone suggest a solution and possibly an explanation of why this does not work?

updated, corrected typo in pasted code.

Comment: That first video is amazing. Also, I think you might mean to have `(currentJointEulerAngles.y > 180f)
    currentJointEulerAngles.y -= 360f;` and `(currentJointEulerAngles.z > 180f)
    currentJointEulerAngles.z -= 360f;` instead of `(currentJointEulerAngles.x > 180f)
    currentJointEulerAngles.x -= 360f;` three times.

Comment: Thanks, good spot. Not sure how I managed to copy the wrong axis in. Possibly copied during one of many unfinished rewrites.
Have corrected the code above.

Comment: If that didn't solve the issue, I think more context/code needs to be seen in order to determine the cause.

Comment: (with the exception of the clamping checks) this, within my for loop is all that is responsible for producing the behaviour in the first video. Hopefully this helps with context? If not, thank you for your effort so far.

Comment: I believe this is a known problem in inverse kinematics called a "singularity" which is caused by there being no uniquely valid solution and the algorithm has trouble selecting a "good enough" one between multiple configurations. See the bottom of https://zalo.github.io/blog/inverse-kinematics/ for an example you can find these singularities in.

One thing you could try is if you exceed the iterations, you generate some more iterations and select the joint configuration among them that minimizes the angle changes of all joints since the last frame and go with that one.